# Updating view after reading data from file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to run jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/rishi007bansod/f7903drg/160/. In this java script, I am taking input from `json` file containing a `json` entry. For example file contains following entry :

```
{
    "a":5,
    "b":2,
    "f": 
    {
        "c":"test",
        "d":"test_json"
    }
}
```

After reading file I am trying to print `json` entry tree structure and assigning `Add Node` and `Delete Node` buttons with each entry to allow addition or deletion of nodes.

In code, I have initialized `$scope.tree` variable to value `$scope.tree = [{name: "myTree", nodes: []}];`. Then, I am trying to assign tree structure to `$scope.tree` variable after reading data from file. But `$scope.tree` variable is not getting updated(its value remains same as what we have initialized). Thus `html` view is not getting updated with this tree after reading data from json file. How can I update this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your function to read in the file data is async, but it does not notify AngularJS that it has completed.

```
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Only angular providers are "synced" with the AngularJS digest cycle (`$q`, `$http`, `$timeout`, etc.). But, plain old document events are not, and must take an extra step to indicate to AngularJS that it needs to run another cycle.

```
 $scope.$apply(function() {
   $scope.tree = myTree;
 });
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/f7903drg/161/

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are updating the `$scope.tree` variable out of the scope of Angular lifecycle, so you need to call `$scope.apply` in `handleFileSelect` function, just at the end, or after assigning the value.

The problem with the input fields of type `file` is that to add an onChange you would need to write a custom directive, because the ng-change is not supported for those fields.